# How can I customize the design of an XP or Windows 7 Explorer window?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I'm trying to recreate what lots of Mac apps have in their installer dmgs - a custom designed finder window that you see when you open the image.

Does anyone know how this is done, and whether or not it can be done on Windows?  I suspect not, but you never know...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be possible in Win98/ME, which allowed you to use HTML to customize folder views.  Unfortunately, this was locked in XP (although the internal folder views still use this technology).

Your best bet is to create a custom app with the window view you'd like and have it autorun.

Also, what you describe goes against Microsoft's UI suggestion of packaging your app in an MSI and letting MSI handle the install.